# MongoDB from bash Syntax Error Unexpected Token :

Tags: mongodb, syntax, mongodb-query

I'm trying to launch a search from a bash shell like that.

```
root@mongo01:~# mongo mydb --quiet --shell --eval "printjson(db.userContests.find({linkId: {$ne: null}}, {linkId: 1}).pretty())"
type "help" for help
2015-02-23T14:45:09.256+0100 SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

As you can see, I get an error.

However, launching the same from mongo shell works.

```
root@axn-mongo01:~# mongo mydb
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.7
connecting to: mydb
> db.userContests.find({linkId: {$ne: null}}, {linkId: 1}).pretty()
{
    "linkId" : "_guid_F5BDEJFk2hvxyamKIVePEw==",
    "_id" : ObjectId("546dc5e47d479b1d0d8b45aa")
}
{
    "linkId" : "_guid_F5BDEJFk2hvxyamKIVePEw==",
    "_id" : ObjectId("546debdf7d479b686f8b458d")
}
{
    "linkId" : "_guid_EcWY0_RmDs8wA2T9LuVAGtiDfUHf8i-jLxTrhDXjzo8=",
    "_id" : ObjectId("546df6237d479b62698b45be")
```

Someone knows what's happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dollar sign `$` is getting interpolated by your shell, you can see what's going on using echo:

```
echo mongo mydb --quiet --shell --eval "printjson(db.userContests.find({linkId: {$ne: null}}, {linkId: 1}).pretty())"
mongo mydb --quiet --shell --eval printjson(db.userContests.find({linkId: {: null}}, {linkId: 1}).pretty())
```

As you can see your shell is parsing `$ne`, which is unset therefore generating invalid syntax.

To fix it use single quotes instead:

```
mongo mydb --quiet --shell --eval 'printjson(db.userContests.find({linkId: {$ne: null}}, {linkId: 1}).pretty())'
```

Comment: You are right in part. but isn't enough. With single quotes ( or escaping dollar sign ) doesn't work.

Comment: Not exactly. It's difficult to explain. You can get the same with,,, mongo admin --quiet --shell --eval 'printjson(db.admin.find())'

Comment: try this: `mongo mydb --quiet <<< 'db.userContests.find({linkId: {$ne: null}}, {linkId: 1})' `

Comment: I *think* the problem is  `--shell` and `--eval` can't be sure. I am glad it helped you.